# Python Dictionary Array - One Line Per Value

Tags: python, dictionary, web-scraping

I have a dictionary with each array containing multiple values.

`upcthreadsmall.txt` contains a series of UPC Numbers "000381001184","000381102935","000381003263" etc.

With the code below it displays as:

```
000381002365 : ['$265.29', '$299.00', '$270.70', '$299.00']
```

I'm wanting it to display as:

```
000381002365 : $265.29
000381002365 : $299.00
000381002365 : $270.70
000381002365 : $299.00
```

**Code:**

```
def th(ur):
    base = "https://www.slickguns.com/search/apachesolr_search/"+ur
    regex = '<td class="price-column">(.+?)</td>'
    pattern = re.compile(regex)
    htmltext = urllib.urlopen(base).read()
    results = re.findall(pattern, htmltext)
    try:
        gmap[ur] = results
    except:"got an error"

upclist = open("upcthreadsmall.txt").read()
upclist = upclist.replace(" ","").split(",")

threadlist = []

for u in upclist:
    t = Thread(target=th,args=(u,))
    t.start()
    threadlist.append(t)

for b in threadlist:
    b.join()


for key, upc in gmap.items():
    print(key)
    for attribute, value in gmap.items():
        print('{} : {}'.format(attribute, value)
```

Comment: Looks like you just need another `for` loop under `for attribute, value in gmap.items():`? `for item in value: print('{} : {}'.format(attribute, item)` But you already seem to understand nested loops so feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: @roganjosh Thank you for the tips.  I believe I already have that in place.

Comment: In that case it should be in your posted code, because if `000381002365 : ['$265.29', '$299.00', '$270.70', '$299.00']` is the actual output from `print('{} : {}'.format(attribute, value)` then you're missing another loop.

Comment: @roganjosh Just noticed this is a endless loop.. Any ideas how to stop it after all dictionary arrays have printed?

Comment: Fixed on my own. Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just create another loop on `value`, and maybe you'd like to sort the attributes:

```
for attribute, value in sorted(gmap.items()):
    for v in value:
        print('{} : {}'.format(attribute, v))
```

Comment: because you already replied in the comments, and I did not want to "farm rep", just wanted to provide some working code. That's my first BTW.

Comment: Thank you. Just noticed this is a endless loop.. Any ideas how to stop it after all dictionary arrays have printed?

Comment: Fixed on my own. Thanks again

Comment: Fair enough, I wouldn't have minded. I'm not usually as fast at getting answers out as you (you've got the gold badge well in your sights), so trying to shoot for more complicated issues :) @hinteractive02 it should not make an endless loop

Comment: yeah gold badge approaching (slowly ...) but I want to deserve each +1 :) good luck out there. There are so many questions needed one or several complementary answers there's room for many :)